# Continuous delivery with Jenkins + Virtualbox

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

Is there a way to integrate virtualbox with jenkins so we can have our deployment pipeline associated with our virtual box machines?

We are currently using the Build Pipeline Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin helps to integrate virtual box with jenkins:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/VirtualBox+Plugin. And Build-pipeline plugin can be deployed anywhere.

Comment: However, how can I keep track of where binaries were generated? So I can always search from a Binary back and find what Virtual Machine, Source Code Revision, etc. was used?